# Yii2 MySQL Order By Relation Count

Tags: php, yii2

Table 1 - User:

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd> <kbd>**`Name`**</kbd>  
<kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`Jonh`</kbd>  
<kbd>`2`</kbd>  <kbd>`Mark`</kbd>  
<kbd>`3`</kbd>  <kbd>`King`</kbd>

---

Table 2 - Book:

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd> <kbd>**`user_id`**</kbd><kbd>**`status`**</kbd> <kbd>**`...`**</kbd>      
<kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      <kbd>`1`</kbd>      <kbd>`...`</kbd>      
<kbd>`2`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      <kbd>`1`</kbd>      <kbd>`...`</kbd>      
<kbd>`3`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      <kbd>`1`</kbd>      <kbd>`...`</kbd>      
<kbd>`4`</kbd>  <kbd>`2`</kbd>      <kbd>`1`</kbd>      <kbd>`...`</kbd>      
<kbd>`5`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      <kbd>`0`</kbd>      <kbd>`...`</kbd>      
<kbd>`6`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      <kbd>`0`</kbd>      <kbd>`...`</kbd>

---

Code:

```
$query = User::find();
$query->joinWith('books');
$query->select(['user.*', 'COUNT(book.id) AS booksCount']);
$query->andWhere(['book.status' => 1]); // Problem Here!
$query->groupBy(['user.id']);
$query->orderBy(['booksCount' => SORT_DESC]);
```

---

Problem:

The `query` is working properly, but it's not returning the user with `id = 3`.
If I remove the line `$query->andWhere(['book.status' => 1]);` it works fine and return all users.

What should I change to list all users, even those who do not have a related book with `status = 1`?

Comment: Your table is called 'books' but your query has 'book', is that the issue?

Comment: @Coz, No, that's correct. My function in the code that have the relation `hasMany` is named `books`, but the table is actually named as `book`. It's working well, just do not returning the `User` with `id = 3` in the list (because it do not have any book with `status = 1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
$query = User::find();

$query->joinWith(['books' => function ($subquery) {
    $subquery->onCondition(['book.status' => 1]);
}]);

$query->select(['user.*', 'COUNT(book.id) AS booksCount']);
$query->groupBy(['user.id']);
$query->orderBy(['booksCount' => SORT_DESC]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `COUNT(book.id)`, if the status of the book is either 0 or 1, you can use `SUM(book.status)` to get the number of books the user has. Then you can remove your `WHERE book.status = 1` clause, and it will return all the users with the number of books they have, even in user 3's case where they have 0 books.

**The Problem**

The real problem is in your where clause. Because `WHERE` is processed before grouping and user 3 doesn't have any rows `where book.status = 1`, then the user has no rows which are included in the base query. Therefor the user isn't present during/after the grouping.

If you want a pretty good idea of a catch-all case where you can count rows based on a condition, using `COUNT(CASE WHEN book.status IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE NULLIF(0,book.status) END)` will also give you the result you're looking for. Because `COUNT()` will not count rows where the expression is `NULL`, this would allow the `book.status` to be -1, 1, 2, and any other number as long as it isn't 0 (or NULL in user 3's case), and still be included in the count.

Comment: This would solve this case, but others might not. So I would like a global response and understand why it's filtering the main table based on the join.